# Print out all of name

Tags: c++

I use pointers to print the contents of a string array for this program, I have trouble in printing out the item's names. Whatever I enter how many items, it prints out only one item. For example, when I entered `pencil, pen, book`, it only printed out the last item 3 times: `book  book  book` instead of printing: `pencil  pen  book`.

```
void getPrint(string *names, int num){
cout <<"Here is the items you entered: ";
for (int i=0; i<num; i++){

    cout <<*names<<"  ";

}
```

Comment: you are passing a pointer to `std::string` and never incrementing it, you should show us how you initialize the data and call the function because the only way I see this working would be by having a `std::string* data = new std::string[num]` which in any case looks like a bad approach since you could use a `std::vector<std::string>` and pass it by `const` reference.

Comment: You are printing the first name `num` times. Try `names[i]` to access the each name by index.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I tried to use it (names[i])) but it only works in int, double, not string

Comment: @symta it sould definitively work with `std::string`. Perhaps the problem lies at the point where you allocate and assign to the array of `std::string` that's given to the function.

Comment: It should print `pencil  pencil  pencil`, not `book  book  book`. And the `[i]` syntax *does* work with strings, of course. So you have not posted the actual code, or only an insufficient portion of it.

Comment: If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved to your satisfaction, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for a full explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want to treat the **pointer to a single string** as an array:

```
void getPrint(string * names, int num)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i)
  {
    cout << names[i] << " ";
  }
  cout << endl;
}
```

There are other possibilities:

```
cout << names++ << " ";
cout << *(names + i) << " ";
```

Look up pointer dereferencing in your favorite reference.

**The preferred solution is to use `std::vector<string>` or `std::array<string>`.**

```
void getPrint(const std::vector<std::string>& names)
{
  const unsigned int quantity = names.size();
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < quantity; ++i)
  {
    std::cout << names[i] << " ";
  }
  std::cout << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilies:

**Array syntax**

Your treat your std::string as an array and increment over its indices. To be consistent you can pass the argument in *array syntax* as well.

```
void getPrint(const std::string names[], const int num){
    std::cout <<"Here is the items you entered: " << std::endl;
    for (int i=0; i<num; i++){
        std::cout <<names[i]<<"  " << std::endl;
    }
}
```

**Pointer syntax**

You pass your std::string as a pointer (on the first element of you array). To reach all your elements you have to increment the pointer itself.

```
void getPrint(const std::string* names, const int num){
    std::cout <<"Here is the items you entered: " << std::endl;
    for (int i=0; i<num; i++){ 
        std::cout <<*(names++)<<"  " << std::endl; // increment pointer
    }
}
```

Since incrementing your pointer does not need the index i anymore you can shorten the whole thing a bit (but may not declare const num anymore).

```
void getPrint(const std::string* names, int num){
    std::cout <<"Here is the items you entered: " << std::endl;
    while(num--){
        std::cout <<*(names++)<<"  " << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Hope I could help you.

**Edit**

As mentioned above any solution using the STL containers std::vector or std::array and passing them by reference are preferred. Since they provide .begin() and .end() methods one can use (C++11)

```
void getPrint(const std::vector<std::string>& names){
    std::cout <<"Here is the items you entered: " << std::endl;
    for (auto name: names){
        std::cout << name << " " << std::endl;
  }
}
```